# How to insert a checkmark in the list in React?

Tags: reactjs

I was working on a ReactJS project. I was trying to display a list of cities, where the list elements are selectable. And when we select a list element, I should display a checkmark at the end of it. I did the display part, but I was not able to insert a checkmark. This checkmark should be there until we deselect it. Can anyone help to solve this issue of inserting a checkmark?

```
function NonIdiomaticList(props) {
  let array = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < props.items.length; i++) {
    array.push(
      <Item key={i} isSelectable item={props.items[i]} />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your entire react component code ? especially the place you are saving the checked items

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a callback for the item selection, this callback has to perform a setState and then you display the checkmark in the item based on a `isSelected` property.

Something like this:

```
function selectItem(index) {
  const selectedIndices = new Set(this.state.selectedIndices);
  if(selectedIndices.has(index)) {
    selectedIndices.delete(index) // Remove if it's already present
  } else {
    selectedIndices.add(index);
  }
  this.setState({selectedIndices}); // This will force the re-render of the component
  return;
}

function NonIdiomaticList(props) {
  let array = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < props.items.length; i++) {
    array.push(
      <Item
         key={i}
         isSelected={this.state.selectedIndices.has(i)}
         onSelect={() => this.selectItem(i)}
         isSelectable
         item={props.items[i]}
       />
    );
  }
```

Remember to bind the selectItem function in the component constructor.
Obviously the `<Item />` component needs to expose those two properties:

1. `isSelected` as boolean
2. `onSelect` as callback

Comment: Your answer allows only one item to be selected at one time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setState to maintain the state of the selected/unselected item.

- Change the item to be a object with selected prop as boolean. Something like this `{name: city, selected: false}`
- Loop over the items and create the list

  `this.state.items.map((item, index) => <Item key={index} selected={item.selected} name={item.name} handleSelect={this.handleSelect(index)})`
- Update the item to be selected on click passing the index of that item

  `handleSelect(i) {
      let {items} = this.state;
      items = items.map((item, index) => {
          if(index === i) {
              item.selected = !item.selected
          }
          return item;
      });
  }`

I have used index for now to select/unselect the item. You can improvise to use uniqueID's or item name itself to achieve the same.